# UIView Block Animation Update Interval

Tags: ios, animation, layer, objective-c-blocks

Is there some kind of update event when a block animation is animating? I'd like to check the frame bounds on every animation update to check if my uiview reached a certain position.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using animation blocks. Instead of updates, though, you'll have an "instructions block" that runs when an animation **completes**. Take a look at this SOF question: [Multistage animation using blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008838/multistage-animation-using-blocks/7009149#7009149)

Comment: I'm not really looking for a complete event, i'm looking for a kind of update event for every animation frame, or every time an animation updates its state. For instance: if a UIView has to move from left to right, i'd like to get informed on every animation frame update that it moved a few pixels and what its current position is to check if I need to move another uiview out of the way.

Comment: hmmm...I'm not sure if we can do that...But if, instead of animating views to move over a distance in one go, we break down the distance into smaller parts and animate them all separately, we can better monitor the animation events and respond accordingly.

Comment: This isn't suitable if your animation doesn't use a linear movement path.

Comment: @MarkIngram It's better to find the relationship between two animations that seem to depend on each other and run the animations separately according to that logic.