# UIView animation end

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation

I am using `UIView` animation in my app:

```
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        //do some animation
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Now, there is a possibility that the animation would take a couple of seconds to finish. So, is there a way to know when the animation has ended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't uses this myself yet, but there is a method setAnimationDidStopSelector that allows you to define a selector that should be called when an animation has finished.

Also see the documentation at Apple for [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).

There is also an example on [Ray Wenderlich's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial) site

Comment: As remarked by tipycalFlow the blocsk will work as well, but will only work on devices running 4 or higher.

Comment: True. Also check out this SOF question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008838/multistage-animation-using-blocks/7009149#7009149

Comment: Nice :), will have to try this at some time

Answer (score 9):

Use the latest block-based animation methods provided by apple as:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                      delay:0.0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState 
                 animations:^{
                     //animation block
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){//this block starts only when 
                 //the animation in the upper block ends
                 //so you know when exactly the animation ends
     }];
```

The method you have used will be deprecated soon...

Comment: It seems that the completion block is animated too, any way can i have the completion block executed immediately?

Comment: Nope...don't think the completion block should take time. Apple's documentation- `A block object to be executed when the animation sequence ends.` You might be missing something...post it as a question if you still find trouble.