# How to state the end of animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, animation, uiviewanimation

Hi i am creating an app which has a animation that plays after a motion and then it goes blank, I need a  way to state in the code when the animation ends play sound, I have the sound code, so I just need to know how to state it, I am using code such as `[animation startanimating]` and `[animation stopanimating]`, `[audioplayer play]` and `[audioplayer stop]`. Thank you I am a beginner so please go easy :)

Comment: Post your entire code please.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the animation? Do you want to flip through an image every second?

Comment: no I have the code for the animation, what i need is once the animation is done I need a piece of music to play

Comment: There are different ways of doing animations. Maybe the way you are doing it is not the best. Could you show the start animations stuff.

Comment: ummm its all the in the paste bin, but i think the problem is that in the code below on the other answer, I don't think it knows when my animation ends, like what picture it ends on??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14190/discussion-between-user1483652-and-eric-brotto)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your code to use a block with a completion callback. Examples in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386186/uiview-animation-end) answer.

---

**edit with example:**

Let's say the view you want to animate is called `myView`

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                  delay:0.0 
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState 
             animations:^{
                 myView.alpha = 0; // a fade out animation
             }
             completion:^(BOOL finished)
             {
                 [audioPlayer play];
                 // whatever else
             }

 ];
```

Is this what you tried? Can you post more actual code? It help to see how you're handling your animation and callback in its entirety.

Comment: Hey, As i stated I am a total beginner and I tried doing that but it didn't work, probably because I'm not doing it right?

Comment: This is how I've done it      completion:^(BOOL finished){
[audioPlayer play];
         play.hidden=0;
         
     };

Comment: Okay I will create a paste bin and put the link here in a few minutes, it will have the whole code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                      delay:0.0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState 
                 animations:^{
                     //animation block
                     // perform animation here
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     // play sound here
                     [audioPlayer play]

     }];
```

Comment: this code is for the animation... so write it when u want to perform the animation...

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to want to use a `CAKeyFrameAnimation`. This will allow you to animate through a series of images with individual frame times **and** get a delegate notification when you have reached the end of your animation, something that animating with an `UIImageView` won't provide.

Some sample code to get you started (assumes ARC):

```
// create an animation overlay view to display and animate our image frames
UIView *animationView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.view addSubview:animationView];

// using 4 images for the example
NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"] CGImage],
                       (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2.png"] CGImage],
                       (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image3.png"] CGImage],
                       (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image4.png"] CGImage],
                       nil];

// change the times as you need
NSArray *keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.25],
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.50],
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],nil];

// animating the contents property of the layer
CAKeyframeAnimation *keyframe = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
keyframe.values = values;
keyframe.keyTimes = keyTimes;
keyframe.calculationMode = kCAAnimationLinear;
keyframe.duration = 1.0;  // 1 second, can be whatever you want, obviously
keyframe.delegate = self;
keyframe.removedOnCompletion = NO;
keyframe.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

// "user defined string" can be whatever you want and probably should be constant somewhere in 
// your source. You can use this same key if you want to remove the animation
// later using -[CALayer removeAnimationForKey:] on the animationView's layer
[animationView.layer addAnimation:keyframe forKey:@"user defined string"];
```

Then, somewhere else, implement your delegate method:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)finished
{
    if ( finished ) {
        // play music
    }
}
```